# Represent decision tree as matrices

Tags: cart, matrix, linear-algebra

Is it possible to use matrix operations to generate node membership for decision trees? In a binary decision tree, each node represents a condition for a single variable. Ignoring the more complicated categorical task, is it possible to multiply a data matrix with a decision tree matrix to generate a matrix for node membership? Where the resulting columns are 1 if a record passes through that node and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Since splits are on inequalities of the variable, I don't think what you want can be done in any reasonable sense.  If $X,Y$ are predictors a split is of the form $ X>4 $ but not even of the form $X+Y >2$, that is the linear algebra operations which matrices represent are not allowed to define the splits.

Comment: What is `decision tree matrix`? How does it look like?

Comment: The `decision tree matrix` is yet to be created. That's what I'm asking about. Is there some matrix that when multiplied by the input data matrix results in a third matrix showing node membership.